# WPF Treeview bind to multiple, nested lists

Tags: wpf, recursion, treeview, datatemplate

I have the below, recursive data structure and I would like to bind it to a tree view.  But I can't work out how to specify my data templates/hierarchical data templates.

```
public class MediaContent
{
    public MediaContent()
    {
        this.Sequences = new List<MediaSequence>();
        this.Items = new List<MediaItem>();
    }

    public List<MediaSequence> Sequences
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<MediaItem> Items
    {
        get;
        set;
    }        
}

public class MediaSequence
{
    public MediaSequence()
    {
        this.Sequences = new List<MediaSequence>();
        this.Items = new List<MediaItem>();
    }

    public List<MediaSequence> Sequences
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<MediaItem> Items
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class MediaItem
{
    public string Filename
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The difficulty comes because each node can contain 2 lists, and the lists are recursive.  Example data is show below.

```
var uberNestedSequence = new MediaSequence();
uberNestedSequence.Items.Add(new MediaItem { Filename = "video1.mp4" });
uberNestedSequence.Items.Add(new MediaItem { Filename = "video2.avi" });

var nestedSequence = new MediaSequence();
nestedSequence.Sequences.Add(uberNestedSequence);

var nestedSequence2 = new MediaSequence();

this.Media.Sequences.Add(nestedSequence);
this.Media.Sequences.Add(nestedSequence2);
```

So, how do I display this data in a WPF Tree view?

```
<TreeView Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Media}">
```

I have tried the below but apparently you cannot specify 2 different templates for the same data type.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MediaSequence}" ItemsSource="{Binding Sequences}">
    <TextBlock Text="sequence" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MediaSequence}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TextBlock Text="item" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: You will either have a tree of type MediaSequence or MediaItem but you cant have both in your tree.

Comment: Would it work if one would use a TemplateSelector???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay lets tackle this in terms of the simplest things first, and it should help to clear out your thinking. It might not look like it but you've not really got anything more complicated than the normal, folders and files heirachy that we usually see.

So if we start with the ends of the trees first, we can define

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MediaItem}">
  <TextBlock Text="item" />
</DataTemplate>
```

We don't any subitems so its just a normal template.

Moving deeper into the tree we now have nodes of `MediaSequence`s which have both items and sequences on them. If only we could treat them as one thing?

Well if we stick to the file system analogy, you find that DotNet defines `FileInfo`s and `DirectoryInfo`s as derivations of the a base `FileSystemInfo`. All we need to do is the same.

```
public interface IMedia
{
  // Actually they have nothing in common
}

public class MediaItem : IMedia
{
  ...
}

public class MediaSequence : IMedia
{
  public IEnumerable<IMedia> Children 
  {
    get
    {
      // This one collection can now expose both types
      // but can be anything behind the scenes
      return Sequences.Concat(Items);
    }
  }
}
```

Which then allows us to define the other template

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MediaSequence}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
  <TextBlock Text="sequence" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

And if you really need to you can define your root as something different too, but its really just a sequence.

```
public class MediaContent : MediaSequence
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: This works great, thanks a lot. I just had to change the children property to first cast each list to IMedia, before calling the concat method, it would not compile otherwise.  I could of course have changed my lists to be of type IMedia, but I prefer the type to be explicit.